# The formula of inverse Meijier-G?

Tags: special-functions, inverse-problems

I have an expression like
$G^{\,2,1}_{1,3} \left(\begin{array}{c}
          a_1\\
          b_1,b_2,b_3
        \end{array}
 \middle\vert\
      z\right)
$,
$a_1,b_1,b_2$ and $b_3$ are fixed number.

I want to know $z$ while $G^{\,2,1}_{1,3} \left(\begin{array}{c}
          a_1\\
          b_1,b_2,b_3
        \end{array}
 \middle\vert\
      z\right) = \varepsilon
$,
where $\varepsilon$ is fixed number.

However, I don't know how to solve this equation, please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your best course of action is likely Newton's method or other root finding algorithms. I don't think at our current level of technology we have the machinery for computing closed form expressions for $z$, given the parameters and $\varepsilon$. I'm going to recommend trying <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen's_method">Steffensen's method</a>  Steffensen's method because that doesn't entail needing to compute the derivative.

Comment: @deoxygerbe Thanks for your kind comments. I'll try it.